# Java multithreading easiest way to run multiple methods at once?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've never had to multithread before, I understand what it is at a basic level. I'm wondering what would be the simplest and most efficent way to execute three methods at once?

e.g

```
public void test(){
method1();
method2();
method3();
}
```

Basically I want to execute 1,2 and 3 at the same time. I'm looking for any examples or resources which would be useful for doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your three methods do not share state, you can just spin up a thread for each method.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: So I would have to make a new class?

Comment: Your class can inherit from `Thread`, or  your class can implement `Runnable`.