# Java Multithreading Class Methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, parallel-processing

I am relativity new to multithreading in Java, and I would like to know if it is possible to execute **a method within a class** in parallel. So instead of this:

```
public void main() {
  this.myMethod();
  this.myMethod();
}
```

... where each method within the class is fired after the previous call has finished, that they would be done in parallel. I know the following example can be done, but that involves creating new classes, which I would like to avoid:

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
  }
}
```

Just to be clear, I have seen [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998699/java-multithreading-easiest-way-to-run-multiple-methods-at-once), but it was of no help me to me.

Is the key to cracking this issue involve using `public static` methods? Either way, could someone please provide an example how to do this with their solution?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, can't be done according to your restrictions. You can't run anything in a Java thread without creating a `Thread` object, and something to contain the `run()` method: either a separate class that implements `Runnable`, or a class that extends `Thread`. The question you pointed to shows exactly what to do; there's no "better" answer, nor indeed *any* other answer.

Comment: Ah... alright. Guess I'll just end up using a bit more code. :) Thanks, Ernest!

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do it like this.  The CountDownLatch and Executors classes are handy utilities from Java 5 to make this kind of stuff easier.  In this particular example the CountDownLatch will block main() until both parallel executions have completed.

(So to answer your question:  it's even worse than you thought!    You have to write even MORE code!)

```
ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public void main() {
  final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(2); // 2 countdowns!
  Runnable r = new Runnable() { public void run() {
    myMethod();
    cdl.countDown();
  } };

  EXECUTOR_SERVICE.execute(r);
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE.execute(r);

  try {
    cdl.await();
  } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
}
```